# Are there any languages that have tones that shift over vowels in a single syllable?

Tags: syllables, tone

I am wondering about [tones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tone_(linguistics)). Specifically, wondering if there are cases where a tone shifts from one vowel to the next, perhaps in some language like Mandarin Chinese or Vietnamese, if not some African language. I don't know much about anything outside of Thai and Mandarin Chinese tones at this point.

But say you have a word like `/ʃiaŋ/`. In Mandarin Chinese, there are several tone variants of that word, like `xiǎng` in Pinyin, which is roughly from my knowledge just `/ʃia˨ŋ/`, where tone 3 in Pinyin is roughly [a low tone](https://www.hackingchinese.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/all-four-tones_low-t3_tone-height-chart_mandarin-chinese_hacking-chinese-1024x312.png). But is there anything like this?

```
ʃi˥a˨ŋ
si˥a˩u˥ŋ
```

Basically, where it changes on a per-vowel basis within a single syllable? If not, how does the tone behave in various languages, or specifically just Mandarin Chinese?

I would like to know what happens when you mix tones with long vowel sequences, like `hoia` or `hoauai` or something complicated. Does anything like this exist?

Comment: _Xiang_ is /ɕaŋ/, not /ʃiaŋ/. In isolation, the third tone will be /ɕaŋ˨˩˦/, with the tone going from mid-low to low to mid-high over the duration of the syllable – this is known as a _contour tone_. The low quality (more precisely mid-low to low) appears in context due to tone sandhi.

Comment: Note that in Mandarin Chinese just one vowel per one syllable is allowed, and what's written in Pinyin as `xiǎng` is pronounced in Beijing as /ɕjɑŋ²¹⁴/, /ɕjɑŋ˨˩˦/, just one vowel /ɑ/, there's no other vowel to shift the tone to.

Comment: Just depends on whether you think a contour tone is really a sequence of tones / tonal targets, and if so whether you think they attach to the vowels. For Thai, Moren and Zsiga have argued for a version of this view (they say the targets attach to morae) but FWIW I'm entirely unconvinced by their analysis. You're still limited to two in a row because you can't have more than two morae in a syllable and you can't have more than one tone (counting contour tones) per syllable.

Comment: @rchivers - Japanese allows three morae per syllable: “entered” 入った (はいった) _haitta_ has 2 syllables  _hait-ta_ with the first syllable having 3 morae:  _ha.i.t-ta_ — 4 morae all in all.

Comment: @YellowSky OK. I was talking about Moren & Zsiga's analysis of Thai but can see how it might have sounded like a general comment.

Comment: @YellowSky That’s assuming the concept of a syllable applies to Japanese at all, or indeed whether sequential vowels are diphthongs or separate vowels. 入った can just as well be sequenced as _ha-i.Q-ta_ (two syllables) or just _ha.i.Q.ta_ (no syllables at all). // Regarding Mandarin, the sandhi spread when a third tone is followed by a neutral tone arguably constitutes a shift, since the underlying contour /˨˩˦/ is spread across two syllables, with the last part of it being associated only with the underlyingly neutral syllable, as in 姐姐 _jiějie_ [tɕe˨˩ tɕe˦].

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - I support the Japanese phonology model described in minor detail in Alpatov, V.M., Vardul, I.F., Starostin, S.A. (2000). _Grammar of the Japanese language. Introduction. Phonology. Supraphonology. Morphology._ Moscow: Publishing House Oriental Literature. (in Russian). In it, morae are made up of phonemes and syllables of morae.

Comment: @YellowSky what about `hái`? Aren't there two vowels there? It would be `h -> low tone a -> high tone a -> regular tone i`, am I wrong?

Comment: Other ones are 有 yŏu, lots of them with `-ai`, 为 wéi, etc. They all seem to have double vowels.

Comment: @LancePollard - Pinyin `you` is pronounced as [jou̯] - one vowel, `-ai` is [ai̯] - one vowel, `wei` is [wei̯] - also one vowel. Here [j] and [w] are glides, [o], [a], and [e] are vowels, [u̯] and [i̯] are finals. Have a look: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Chinese_phonology#Syllables

Comment: I'll have a look, but I don't get it, `a` is a vowel and `i` is a vowel, so how is `ai` one vowel.

Comment: the 'i' in this case is acting as a consonant, like in a word like 'day', you only pronounce it as one syllable, with the last 'i' being a glide, or non-syllabic vowel.

Comment: `i` is a consonant? The way I have been looking at things, even if you **blend** vowels together into one syllable (huai), there are still 3 vowels even though they blend together into one syllable. That is what I was asking, how the tone integrates with these 3 blended vowels. Calling `i` a consonant seems, well, like saying "z" or "b" is a vowel or something.

Comment: @LancePollard You’re conflating letters and sounds. Letters are irrelevant, they’re only used when we need to communicate language through a soundless medium. Vowels and consonants are not clearly separable from a phonetic point of view – glides can have properties of both, for example – but in most languages, they behave differently systematically. In Mandarin, a syllable can have only one vocal peak (= vowel), otherwise it’s two syllables; compare 癌 _ái_ [ai̯˧˥] ‘cancer’ (one vowel, one syllable) with 阿姨 _āyí_ [a˥.i˧˥] ‘aunt’ (two vowels, two syllables). Also, _z_ is a vowel [z̩] in _bzzz_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is such a thing as "tone shift", which is especially widespread in Bantu languages (see  Kisseberth & Odden (2003) in *The Bantu languages*). Shifting can be by a vowel (mora), a syllable, or multiple syllables. Shifting by a vowel vs. a syllable are the same thing, except when you are dealing with long vowels / diphthongs, and syllable-internal shifts from one mora to the next are not common, but they exist. However, as K&O point out, "shift" can arguably always be reduced to assimilation (spread) plus disassociation, and there are numerous cases where spreading is more general and disassociation is more restricted, giving a mixed case where you have both spread and shift.
Please note that a "shift" in tone is a movement from one underlying position to a different surface position.

Your question / example seems to be more about contouring patterns within a syllable. There are two sub-parts to the question. The first is, how many tonal targets can there be in a syllable? That is kind of a highly language-specific question, but there are languages known to have three tones on a single short vowel. There has been a bit of distraction in the literature over the difference between length and duration, because it takes longer to produce a HLH contour on a vowel that to produce a simple H, so you have to apply phonological criteria to decide if a vowel is long, versus has "greater duration" (than...). The absolute max in the attested contours as far as I know is a four-tone complex in claimed to be Lomongo, but I won't vouch for that, but three-element contours are common enough.

The second part is, to what extend can the movement-points in a multi-toned syllable be contrastive. As far as we know, there is only one kind of short rise or short fall, assuming a language with just H and L tones (with 3 levels, you can have many more kinds of rise and fall). You also do not find multiple types of rise and fall on long syllables, even though [v́v̂] vs [v́v̀] would be perfectly sensible from a theoretical perspective. There may be functional and historical reasons why such a contrast doesn't exist. (There is a controversial claim about Shilluk, which would have a separate paper to review). One formal explanation for the syllable-internal restriction is that tones are properties of syllables, not individual vowels.